# Magento products sold at price zero and only shipping was charged

Tags: php, magento

I am working on E-Commmerece site which is based on Magento Enterprise Edition 1.11.2.0. I have found a problem recently where one of our customers purchased 3 different types of  products with respective quantities 8,8,6.

In which only shipping was charged and products prices become zero. `The actual product price was $8.99.`

I have checked no promotion rule was applied on this order.

when I saw the order from admin side only products sku's were visible and name's of products were not displaying and product prices were zero.

Customer used paypal express checkout for payment and his payer status is unverified. Rest of orders being placed near this order are perfect.

Can any one tell me what had gone wrong in this order?

Comment: Have you tried recreating the same scenario from your end?

Comment: yes i have tried the same.
but in my case every thing is fine.
only in that case having problem.

Comment: I have again found this problem again. In this time customer added two products of quantity of 2 for both. So can anyone tell me how is this possible, why the products prices become zero for the particualr order ......can anyone please tell me what i do..........

Comment: In further investigation i found when products added to the cart that time the products price is become zero for cart only, but how is this done still i am not getting this.